# Top margin inside a div do not work?

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains links (a href). All other margins are working with a href but Top margin is not working with a href. I want to place links in middle but because of not working of top margin it is not being possible. I heared by setting position or display it can work. Please suggest a cross broswer solutions for it.

```
div.MainContainer div.Links
{
    height: 57px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 0px #404040;
    border-left: solid 2px #404040;
    border-right: solid 2px #404040;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #404040;
    background-image: url("../Images/links_background.png");
}
div.MainContainer div.Links a
{
    font:12px verdana;
    color:White;
    margin:10px;
    border:dashed 1px white;
    margin:15px 20px 20px 20px ;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: if you are trying to move the links down within the div, have you tried padding?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to float element to make margin working or use padding instead.

```
div.MainContainer div.Links a
{
    float: left;
    font:12px verdana;
    color:White;
    margin:10px;
    border:dashed 1px white;
    margin:15px 20px 20px 20px ;
    width:100px;
}
```

Comment: It is weird, but it is working tho. It works in IE 7 normally.

Comment: why we need to float element if we want `margin-top` to be working..??

Comment: @shashwat Because it's CSS, don't seek for a reason.

Answer (score 4):

Height of inline elements can't be changed, just use `display:inline-block;` on your links.

Comment: **+1** but, margin doesn't affect the height of elements, and height's on inline elements can be changed. however `display: inline-block` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Try below.  I added `overflow: hidden` to the top definition and `display: block` and `float: left` to the bottom definition.  The first addition clears the float being added, and the last two allow the margin on the links to work correctly.

```
div.MainContainer div.Links
{
    height: 57px;
    width: 100%;
    border-top: solid 0px #404040;
    border-left: solid 2px #404040;
    border-right: solid 2px #404040;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #404040;
    background-image: url("../Images/links_background.png");
    overflow: hidden;
}
div.MainContainer div.Links a
{
    font:12px verdana;
    color:White;
    margin:10px;
    border:dashed 1px white;
    margin:15px 20px 20px 20px ;
    width:100px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `padding-top` on the `div.Links` rather than `margin-top` on the `div.Links a`.

Answer (score 0):

use `padding-top: 1px` (at least) for the `div.Links` and you don't need to use float on the `div.Links a`